# Data Factory v2 copy from FTP strange fails

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to binary copy a few .ZIP files sequentially from FTP to ADLS. Sometimes its failed, sometimes not, it's really strange for me. I got this type of error only working with this external FTP server. 
Error type:

> {
>       "errorCode": "2200",
>       "message": "Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToReadFtpData,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to read data from ftp: The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.,Source=System,'",
>       "failureType": "UserError",
>       "target": "Copy from FTP"
>   }

A connection is good, as I said sometimes it copy files without any errors, this is a simple activity so I don't know what can cause this type of error. 
Sometimes it throws an error after copying 50mb on adls. 
Can it be related to the FTP server?

Comment: @FangLiu is this familiar to you maybe?

Comment: You mean the same linked service sometimes work, sometimes not? What is your authentication type? Does it pass test connection in UI?

Answer (score 1):

A possible root cause could be :
Your FTP server does not support SSL but you enabled SSL in the FTP linked service. If so, You can disable the SSL in FTP linked service. Check out the FTP properties here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-ftp-connector

Comment: Thanks for you answer. SSL was disabled all time and yes sometimes it works sometimes not. Also this error is not clear to me, it seems like he lose connection in some moment, a file that I transforming is around 1gb so. I tested connection from UI and it is succesful.  Also i can see all files when i go browse folder.

Comment: I can share pipelineRunId if that can be helpful. 
For example: I have retry policy set on 3. First two times activity fails, third time succeed

Comment: Yes, you could provided an activity runid for the failed one.

Comment: f5776807-a43c-4464-897c-0e6b3b8f5bd4 here you and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From telemetry, it shows Copy can sometimes pass or fail with same payload, so it looks like a transient failure. But it is hard to determine the RCA from error message ("530 Not logged in"). What I'm suspecting is Copy hit throttling or similar transient issue from FTP server which will block the read request in the middle.

For further troubleshoot, could you check from FTP server side to see whether there's any detailed failure log. Besides, it will be a great help if I can get a test account to test the FTP server behavior and try to repro the issue. Please let me know if it is possible for you.

Regards,
Gary

Comment: Thanks, @Gary. Problem is that this is an external company and their server. I will contact them and see what can I do. Is there a news about auto-resume function? Once again, thanks for your time guys.